# 'clUnloadCompiler': was declared deprecated when trying to compile OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am trying to compile [this](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/). I am using the [AMD SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/). I am using the header files that come with the aforementioned SDK and they are located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include\CL
```

The tutorial states:

**Header files**
Just like any other external API used in C++, you must include a header file when using the OpenCL™ API. Usually, this is in the directory CL within the primary include directory. For the C++ bindings we have (replace the straight C API with cl.h):

I found that last bit a little confusing. I am using both .h and .hpp

```
#include <CL/cl.h> when this is used it will compile the checkErr function
#include <CL/cl.hpp> when this is used it gives me access to the cl namespace
```

When I try to compile this code it fails with:

```
'clUnloadCompiler': was declared deprecated
```

[image]

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS (after removing #include <CL/c.h>)**

It now gives the following list of errors:
[image]

```
error C4996: Error  2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _clReleaseCommandQueue@4 referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<struct _cl_command_queue *>::release(struct _cl_command_queue *)" (?release@?$ReferenceHandler@PAU_cl_command_queue@@@detail@cl@@SAHPAU_cl_command_queue@@@Z)    


error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _clReleaseContext@4 referenced in function "public: static int __cdecl cl::detail::ReferenceHandler<struct _cl_context *>::release(struct _cl_context *)" (?release@?$ReferenceHandler@PAU_cl_context@@@detail@cl@@SAHPAU_cl_context@@@Z)
```

In properties for my project I have:

1. added C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include\ as an additional include directory
2. added C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64 as an additional library directory
3. added OpenCL.lib as an additional dependency

The errors I listed happen regardless of whether or not I take the last two steps. That is, the last two do not seem to be helping or harming anything

Comment: For a C++ application, you should only need cl.hpp. Have you tried removing `#include <CL/cl.h>`?

Comment: Hi, okay I just removed it and I understand that it was messing up because I was including c and c++ headers. but now it is giving new errors. I explain the new errors in the question.

Comment: First, try "rebuild" instead of just "build". Is there more than one OpenCL.lib available? You might try the other one. If that doesn't work, make sure the command that Visual Studio is issuing includes "OpenCL.lib" in it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it worked! I switched the include library to x86 and did a rebuild. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I have now answered in "answer" form ... :)

Comment: @user1873073 - Also, please try to post text in questions the next time - not images of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary of answers I provided in comments:

1. For a C++ application, you only need to `#include <CL/cl.hpp>`
2. Make sure you are linking with the correct OpenCL.lib (32-bit vs. 64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

That's because `clUnloadCompiler()` was deprecated in OpenCL 1.2.

Add

```
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS
```

to your code before

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
```